# PassportJS how to check if user is logged in?

Tags: session, express

How can I check if the user is logged in in an ExpressJS/[PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) app? I believe PassportJS will set the session automatically? But what variable does it set?

Answer (score 2):

`session.passport.user` which is set when calling `req.logIn` and unset when calling `req.logOut`

```coffeescript
sessionStore = new MongoStore # RedisStore or whatever

sessionStore.get data.sessionID, (err, session) ->
  if session.passport.user?
     # Logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got it set up correctly, you should be able to see the Set-Cookie line in the HTTP response after POSTing to your session creation route (try `curl -v -d "username=whoever&password=supersecret" http://localhost:3000/session/new` with the appropriate substitutions for username, password and url).

However, to answer your question directly, you should be seeing `connect.sid` and `remember_token` by default. If you're not seeing this set, but can still dump a valid user object in your authentication strategy, verify that you've got the following lines in your `app.configure` call:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: "replace"}); // lots of options here, read up
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

In connect.js you should check for `request.user` in your middleware

[How to know if user is logged in with passport.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739725/how-to-know-if-im-logged-in-with-passport)