# Routing on the server messes up routing on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

Using passport.js I don't need any client side javascript until the user is logged in.

On my server side, I have a router that handles some login logic. So when the user successfully logs in, I route the user to the `/profile` route.

This kind of confuses me, since express is handling the overall framework. The `/profile` route renders my profile template `res.render('profile', { user : req.user });` and nicely passes in the server model for the user into the template, cool stuff!

But this is what gets me, if my app is now on `/profile` a path that doesn't exist in my directory and I define my directory here `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` this results in bad architecture.

Because at times I get 404 errors on my js css. I have to route like this `/routes#chat` on my client side backbone router.

**My Question**

So would it be a good idea to somehow after user success to redirect back to `localhost:3000` and now destroy the login view and render a user profile view? Could someone kind of give me an insight how I could route like that, I have a general idea but not so sure how to do that when I think the server side would need to communicate with the client side, or maybe not?

If the above is a bad idea, can someone give me advice on how to better look at this?

**Edit:** Routes

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index'); 
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
});

app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', { user : req.user });
    res.redirect('/');
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.userName = req.user.local.email;
        users[socket.userName] = socket;
        console.log(Object.keys(users))
    });
});
```

Comment: base `/` server route first check `isLogin`, if true render `profile`, false render/direct to `/login`. once logon redirect to `/`

Comment: Yeah I tried that, so I get the user is saved in the session. But when redirected to `/` how to I pass the users properties to the template. If I redirect to `/` it would use my index.handlebars which contains two buttons, login or sign up.

Comment: I mean your index.handlerbar need to be profile page. your current index become login.handlerbar.

Comment: Oh makes sense I wasn't thinking like that. Thanks let me try to change it up.

Comment: Okay I get what you're saying to an extent. My problem is if I set my default route, whenever I route back to that it runs the initial route. So by routing back to `/` it runs whatever is set.

Comment: I mean for example even if I 
`app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login'); 
});`
This is cool, but when I redirect after `isLoggedIn` itll re-render the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use session to remember the login or use some custom function to query the status of login.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    if (req.session.isLogin) {
        res.render('profile', { user : req.user });
        // put other code here
    }
    else
        res.redirect('/login'); 
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
});
```

Comment: Oh great, I'm new to routing and all this stuff. I appreciate the example. Glad you responded I was fiddling my sanity away :)

Comment: My route middleware looks like this `function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
   return next();
  res.redirect('/');
 }`

But `req.session.isLoggedIn` seems to return undefined?

Comment: So since I am using passport.js it seems I needed to use `req.user` it works, not sure if its safe?? but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739725/how-to-know-if-user-is-logged-in-with-passport-js

Comment: Is `if (req.user)` a good solution instead of `if (req.session.isLogin)` sound off and ill for sure give you a green check. Thanks for the insight....

Comment: did you use passport.js for auth? or I mistaken from any other question.

Comment: Yeah I am not an expert by any means so take it with a grain of salt when I say "yes I did". I followed this awesome tutorial http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local my understanding has tremendously grown, I am pretty confident passport handles the auth.

Comment: I should have definitely mentioned that in the question. I see passport does handle sessions `app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions` so yeah seems like this problem is solved. I liked your answer because the routing scheme is perfect. It works great thanks!!!