# Unable to access req.user with Passport.js and Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, passport.js

I've been creating an app with Passport, Express 4 and Jade. I would like to show the user a navbar that changes when they log in.

However, I cannot access req.user for any other page than the profile page, which calls isLoggedIn:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next()

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect("/login")
}
```

Using any other function to not redirect the user when not logged in results in req.user being `undefined`. I get the user like this:

```
router.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render("profile", {
    title: 'Gebruikersprofiel van ' + req.user.firstname + " " + req.user.lastname,
    user: req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    })
})
```

And without the call to isLoggedIn (this doesn't work):

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    // serve index.html
    res.render("index", {
        title: 'Home',
        user: req.user,
        message: req.flash("message") 
    })
})
```

`isLoggedIn` is outside `module.exports = function(passport) { /* all routes */ }`, the rest is (of course) in it.

Setup of the app is as follows:

```
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongodb = require("mongodb"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    uriUtil = require("mongodb-uri"),
    morgan = require("morgan"),
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
    session = require("express-session"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    flash = require("connect-flash"),
    ip = "okay",
    port = process.env.PORT || 80

require("./includes/passport")(passport)
require("./includes/subject")
require("./includes/user")

var app = new express()
app.disable("x-powered-by")
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.use(morgan("dev")); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: "yep" })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


app.set("view engine", "jade")
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"))

/**
 * CORS support.
 */
//skipped

//Database setup skipped

/**
 * App setup
 */
// make our db accessible to our router - globals
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.db = db
    next()
})

var api = require("./routes/api")(passport),
    web = require("./routes/web")(passport)

// /api for api routes and / for web routes
app.use("/api", api)
app.use("/", web)

//Error handling skipped

// fire in the hole!
app.listen(port, ip, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port)
})
```

I have tried various things, including adding middleware in app.js to add the user to res.locals.user, but none have worked for me, so far.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I've not seen many people mention it, but would [StormPath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/index.html) maybe be a better solution?

**Edit 2**: I am using Stormpath for now, but would still happily take suggestion on how to solve this, if anyone has any.

**Edit 3**: I have gotten a number of requests to see the (de)serializeUser functions. They are as follows:

```
// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried calling `require("./includes/passport")(passport)` after `app.use(passport.session());`?

Comment: I just tried this, it didn't work. What I see is the user is not getting deserialized, every page can only access the user that logged in from a redirect by that page (so a login per page seems to work, but is of course not the way I want it to be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. It was in the way I linked the pages of my site, which made it start a new session from the profile page onto the rest of the site.

The answer can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314240/1218007